# Unhashable When Comparing Lists

Tags: python-3.x, nltk

I am not familiar with the unhashable error that I am receiving here. I have the following dataframe 'dfd' that I am isolating role descriptions on. From there, I split each word within the role descriptions out and consolidate the entire list together into a single list. From this list, I try and compare this to a list of stop words that will filter out the clutter.

This code fails at the if statement:
    *if w not in stop_words:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'*

Could someone explain what the issue is? I feel like this should be straightforward.

```
dfd = dfd['Role Description']

mylist =[]
for role in dfd:
    tokenized_word=word_tokenize(role)
    mylist.append(tokenized_word)

stop_words=set(stopwords.words("english"))

map(str, mylist)

print(mylist)

filtered_sent=[]
for w in mylist:
    if w not in stop_words:
        filtered_sent.append(w)
print("Filtered Sentence:",filtered_sent)
```

Comment: can you add the actual traceback?

Answer (score 0):

Question solved. The list was not flattened, so I was running a list of lists through this instead of each individual item